# CSS flex children gutters with margin

Tags: html, css

I have a gallery layout, and I want to separate every box with margin. The problem is the last box in every row is not align with the grid; there is still space on the right side, how can I do this without using padding? ( that will force me to add another wrapper div )

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.align-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.space-between {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
nav {
  background: #464646;
  height: 70px;
}
.box {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1em;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1em);
  -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1em);
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1em);
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container flex align-center space-between">

    <ul>
      <li>Logo</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>

</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="gallery flex">
    <div class="box">BOX 1</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 2</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 3</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Note:** I can't use flex grow: 1 because I don't always have two boxes in a row.

I can't use space between because the grid is dynamic so for example If the width of the box is 33.33% and you have five boxes, the second row will be with two boxes one on the left side and second on the right side.

Comment: Great question. Would be useful to only post the relevant HTML / CSS. It would make it easier easier to read.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Method # 01:**

Add following css on parnet and child respectively (This method will work only when there are only 2 boxes in a row):

```
/* For Parent Element */
.flex {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

/* For Child Element */
.flex-child {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 0.5em);
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.align-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.space-between {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
nav {
  background: #464646;
  height: 70px;
}
.box {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1em;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 0.5em);
  -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 0.5em);
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 0.5em);
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container flex align-center space-between">
    <ul>
      <li>Logo</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery flex space-between">
    <div class="box">BOX 1</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 2</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 3</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 4</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 5</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 6</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 7</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 8</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Method # 02:**

1. Add margin on both sides of child elements.
2. Extend parent from left/right with same amount of negative margin.

***Note***: Add `overflow: hidden` on parent of `.gallery` if horizontal scroll appears.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -0.5em;
}
.align-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.space-between {
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
nav {
  background: #464646;
  height: 70px;
}
.box {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1em;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1em);
  -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1em);
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1em);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0.5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="container flex align-center space-between">
    <ul>
      <li>Logo</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="gallery flex">
    <div class="box">BOX 1</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 2</div>
    <div class="box">BOX 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did not like this solution because I need to maintain both the container and the child's. I will wait for more answers.

Comment: But now I can't control the space width

Comment: @RedJohn I've added another variant which is more appropriate as for me.

Comment: @RedJohn I think you can. You can use `px` instead of `em`.

Comment: Your first solution is not okay. Change the boxes to be 3 in a row and then add two more at the second row. The greed needs to be flexible.

Comment: @RedJohn I've added and looks fine..? Is it not looks fine?

Comment: If the width of the box is 33.33% and you have five boxes, the second row will be with two boxes one on the left side and second on the right side.

Comment: @RedJohn I've assumed before posting solution that you will have only 2 boxes in a row. If you have more than 2 I'll suggest you to use 2nd method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `gap` / `row-gap` / `column-gap`:

```css
.flex: {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}
```

See more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#gap-row-gap-column-gap)

Answer (score 0):

Just change two things :-

1. Remove margin-right: 1em; style from box class.
2. Add a new style justify-content: space-between; in your flex class.

Comment: But now I can't control the space width

Comment: Do you have control on box sizes ?

Comment: Your solution is not okay. Change the boxes to be 3 in a row and then add two more at the second row. The greed needs to be flexible.

Answer (score -1):

**check snippet below.  its solved**

Use CSS

> box:nth-child(2n+1){margin-left:0px;}

```css
   

 * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .flex {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .align-center {
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .space-between {
      -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
    }
    .container {
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0 1em;
      border: 1px solid;
    }
    nav {
      background: #464646;
      height: 70px;
    }
    .box {
      background: lightblue;
      padding: 1em;
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -webkit-flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1em);
      -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1em);
      flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 1em);
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 2em;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      }
    .box:nth-child(2n+1){
      margin-left:0px;
      }
```

```html
   

 <nav>
      <div class="container flex align-center space-between">

        <ul>
          <li>Logo</li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
          <li>Home</li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <header>
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </header>

    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="gallery flex">
        <div class="box">BOX 1</div>
        <div class="box">BOX 2</div>
        <div class="box">BOX 3</div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Explanation please.

Comment: use nth-child(2n+1){margin-left:0px;}. its take margin left 0 after 2 box

Comment: if you notice, the gutter space in between two boxes has increased.! This is not in case of @RedJohn's question